# A way to shutdown without screen

Tags: display, shutdown

I am using a Grundig Smart TV as a display for my PC running Ubuntu 18.04. If I forget to turn on the TV before starting the PC, the PC cannot detect the TV as a display even after I turned the TV on. I am looking for a way to shutdown my PC without having feedback via the display, since otherwise I have to resolve the issue by cutting the power to the PC and turning the TV and the PC on in the right order.

Comment: Check for a BIOS Setting: Power button press (not hold). Suspend vs Reboot vs (graceful) ACPI Poweroff.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy!